# How to hide logo if there is no logo?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-bootstrap Thumbnails to show a bunch of logo.

If there is no logo then I am setting a default logo.

But now I want the default logo also should not show.
So,if I remove the default logo, then I am getting the breakup image.

Here is the code -->

```
function ExpoCard({
  data
}) {
const {logo} = data;
let defaultLogo = 'defaultLogo.png';
const URL = `${CLOUDINARYURL}/${isDisplayPage ? displayImgConfig : imgConfig}/${IMAGE_URL}${logo || defaultLogo}`;

  <Thumbnail
            src={URL}
            alt={name}
            onClick={() => setData && setData(data)}
            className={cx('expo-card-thumbnail', setData && !isDisplayPage && 'cursor exhibitor-logo-portal-page')}
          >
            {!hideBoothName && (
              <div
                className={cx(
                  boothSize === 'LARGE' || boothSize === 'MEDIUM' ? 'expo-title-large' : 'expo-title-small',
                  'ex-title-name',
                )}
                style={{ color: nameColor || '#000000' }}
              >
                <LinkWithTooltip isText tooltip={name} placement="top">
                  {name}
                </LinkWithTooltip>
              </div>
            )}

            {categoryName && <div className="ex-tag-line">{categoryName}</div>}
            <div>
              {shortDescription && (
                <>
                  <LinkWithTooltip isText tooltip={shortDescription} placement="top">
                    <div className="expo-card-desc-container m-t-5">
                      <div
                        className={cx(
                          boothSize === 'LARGE'
                            ? 'expo-card-desc-large'
                            : boothSize === 'MEDIUM'
                            ? 'expo-card-desc-medium'
                            : 'expo-card-desc-small',
                          'expo-card-desc',
                        )}
                        style={{ color: shortDescriptionColor || '#000000' }}
                      >
                        {shortDescription}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </LinkWithTooltip>
                </>
              )}
            </div>
            <div className="card-footer">
              {isShowAvailability && !isDisplayPage && !disableChat && !isSearching && status && (
                <span className={cx('ex-status-label', status)} style={{ position: 'absolute' }}>
                  {status}
                </span>
              )}
              {!isDisplayPage
                ? data.sponsorUrl !== '' && (
                    <a
                      className="viewExpoBtn"
                      role="button"
                      tabIndex="0"
                      aria-label={name}
                      onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' && setData && setData(data)}
                    >
                      <i className="ac-icon-arrow-right pull-right btn" />
                    </a>
                  )
                : (data.linkToSite || data.sponsorUrl) && (
                    <a
                      className="viewExpoBtn"
                      role="button"
                      tabIndex="0"
                      aria-label={name}
                      onKeyPress={(e) => e.key === 'Enter' && setData && setData(data)}
                    >
                      <i className="ac-icon-arrow-right pull-right btn" />
                    </a>
                  )}
            </div>
          </Thumbnail>
}
```

I was thinking of creating a class display-none and when there is no logo, Thumbnail should add display-none class but if I do so,everything gets hidden including name.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. Instead of hiding the Thumbnail itself just hide the IMG element inside with CSS child selectors.
   You can do something like:

   ```
   .hide-thumbnail >img{
      display:none;
   }
   ```

Add this `hide-thumbnail` class to Thumbnail when you don't want a picture to show up.

2. Set a 0 size picture as the default logo:
   You can create an empty picture in paint on Windows and use that as the default picture
3. Move everything out of Thumbnail into a different Component and show Thumbnail along the new component only when you need it.

Option 1 and 2 are not great but can work as a quick solution.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do 1 & 2 ?